# IOS Webview slow on iPad 1 and iPhone 3gs

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I'm currently developing an iPhone app with a webview. The app works on every device higher than an iPad 1 or iPhone 3gs but on those two devices it running slow after about 5 min.

It just a simple app with a webview, and when I try it on the iPad 2 is runs smooth.
The website i'm loading has some javascript but it works on the safari browser of the iPad 1 and the iPhone 3gs.

Does anybody know what's going wrong?

Thx!

Comment: These two devices are older and less powerful in terms of RAM and CPU. So it could be that this is the only cause for the reduced performance that you mention.

Comment: But why is the code working smooth on the mobile safari browser? It should also be slow in safari but there it runs just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use ARC but found the problem.

In the app I use the Reachability class from apple to check if the device has an internet connection. My loading function was looping and the apps keeps testing the connection.

After I changed the loading function to check the connection only once the problems is gone!